# Is there a way to shorten 'greater than' operator condition?

Tags: mysql, operators

This is the code

```
SELECT name FROM world
  WHERE population >
     (SELECT population FROM world
      WHERE name='Romania')
```

**I want to know if the following part can be shortened.**

```
     (SELECT population FROM world
      WHERE name='Romania')
```

I'm new to MYSQL. Sorry for such questions.

Thank You

Comment: only if you already know population of "Romania" :)

Comment: @2oppin Ahh okay. Thanks.  +1

Comment: There's no particular reason to shorten it. The execution time will be spent in `SELECT name FROM world WHERE population > `, not here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While probably of little help in this query (as the sub query is only returning a single record), it is often faster to use a join rather than a sub query.

```
SELECT w1.name 
FROM world w1
INNER JOIN world w2 ON w1.population > w2.population
WHERE w2.name = 'Romania'
```

You would probably want an index on the name field, and another index on the population field for reasonable performance.